# Is it gramatically incorrect to begin a sentence with 'But'?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I am wondering because I was told that it is, but from what I've seen it's pretty widely used.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I searched for an existing one but no success. That answers my question!

Comment: Whoever told you that should butt out.  But that's just my personal opinion.